# Only the first character displays in (HTML) listbox elements after async call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, angularjs, internet-explorer-9

I have a question about AngularJS/IE9.

I have modal window with patient list.

```
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">Patient list</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <div>
         <input class="form-control" ng-model="searchText"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <select size="15" class="list-group">
            <option ng-repeat="patient in patientList | filter:searchText" ng-click="..">
                {{patient.patientName}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Patient list loaded with $http factory

```
.factory('patientService', function ($http) {
    return {
        getPatientList: function () {
            return $http.get("Api/Patient/GetFullPatientList")
                .then(function (results) {
                    return results.data;
                }, function (results) {
                    console.log("Error: " + results.data + "; " + results.status);
                });
        };
```

So, this service inject to PatientController

```
function PatientController($scope, $modalInstance, patientService) {
    $scope.patientList = patientService.getFullPatientList();
}
```

In Chrome, FF, Safari I get correct view of patient listbox on UI, but in IE9 I get follow screen: http://take.ms/m0mFz 
Only first symbols in list items shows.

When, I replace listbox on (for example) simple list - all works fine.

I think, it happens because data loaded with async call, and IE no refresh data.
So, I try do it smth like this:

```
    function PatientController($scope, $modalInstance, patientService) {
        $scope.patientList = patientService.getFullPatientList().then(function(data){
            $scope.patientList = data;
            $scope.$apply();
        });
    }
```

But it's also did not bring results.

Please, help or advice me :)
Thanks!

Comment: can you make fiddle example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with incorrect listbox display. By default, in IE9, "display" property in select styles is unspecified.

I resolve it with JQuery code:

```
patientService.getFullPatientList().then(function(data) {
    $scope.patientList = data;
    $('.list-group').width('95%'); //SOLVE
});
```